# Why do multiple functions use less memory than one large function with multiple variables

Tags: c++, memory-management, binary-search-tree

I was doing a Leetcode challenge and my code used about .5 kb of memory more than other submissions that looked more complex. The challenge itself was inverting a binary tree. Although I submitted my solution multiple times to take the average values of runtime and memory usage for my code.
My code below runs on average for 3ms and takes 8.5 kb of memory after 10 trial submissions.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {
       if(root == nullptr) return root;
     
       invertTree(root -> left);
       invertTree(root -> right);
        
       TreeNode* tmp = root ->left;
        root -> left = root -> right;
        root -> right = tmp;
        return root;

    }
};
```

The code below is the sample submission that Leetcode shows as an example of 0ms runtime and 8kb of memory usage

```
class Solution {
public:
    void invert(TreeNode* root)
    {
        if(root==nullptr)
            return;
        invert(root->left);
        invert(root->right);
        TreeNode* temp = root->right;
        root->right = root->left;
        root->left = temp;
    }
    TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root==nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        invert(root);
        return root;
    }
};
```

I am wondering how the code given uses two functions and uses less memory than my solution? Additionally, I am relatively new to programming, and am wondering if this case is exemplary of deeper mechanic within the C++ language or too nitpick-y to warrant any concern. Thanks for reading

Comment: Cpp compilers are really smart these days, so they may inline small functions like this if necessary.

Comment: It's only a guess, maybe because of `return root`  in your function? The other recursive function doesn't return anything. Who knows how it was optimized on their machine.

Comment: Your solution pushes nodes onto the stack as it recurses down, which will take more space if the tree is very deep.

Comment: Looking [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nxojxc) - both versions generate the same assembly language with gcc 10.1 at `-O2` optimisation level.  I guess whatever website you're using is just using some other compiler or version of GCC or another optimisation level where it's arbitrarily worse for your version of the code.

Comment: OK so after a couple more problems, I have found that the diagnostics that any submission receives vary wildly each time you send in the exact same code. Even when I copy paste the fastest and slimmest code segment examples I still get a wide variety of results, all of which are worse than the diagnostics that the website had given to that code initially. I think because the service is based on a freemium business model, letcode might reserve its computing power for premium subscribers.